# Delphi TJSONPairEnumerator.GetCurrent not expanded

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I have hints after build project in Delphi XE5:

```
[dcc32 Hint] unit.pas(140): H2443 Inline function 'TJSONPairEnumerator.GetCurrent' has not been expanded because unit 'Data.DBXPlatform' is not specified in USES list
```

It refers to:

```
uses
  System.Generics.Collections, Data.DBXJSON, System.IOUtils,
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes;
    ...
    var
    wzorKlucz: string;
    begin
     enum := wzor.GetEnumerator;

     while enum.MoveNext do
      ...
      wzorKlucz := enum.Current.JsonString.Value; //here
      ...
```

How can I disable hint for this line, or what I have is not correct ?

Comment: Have you even read the hint message? It says what you have to do.

Comment: Sorry, probably I misread Data.DBXJSON with Data.DBXPlatform

Comment: Not only does the hint say what to do, but the hint has a number which leads to documentation `http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/H2443_Inline_function_'%25s'_has_not_been_expanded_because_unit_'%25s'_is_not_specified_in_USES_list_(Delphi)`  A mistake that many people make is to ignore the content of messages.  What you should take away from this is a renewed enthusiasm for reading error messages, trying to understand them, and looking them up in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hint says, `Data.DBXPlatform` is not in your `uses` list. Just add it there:

```
uses
  System.Generics.Collections, Data.DBXJSON, System.IOUtils,
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, 
  Data.DBXPlatform;
```

> This situation may occur if an inline function refers to a type in a
>   unit that is not explicitly used by the function's unit. For example,
>   this may happen if the function uses inherited to refer to methods
>   inherited from a distant ancestor, and that ancestor's unit is not
>   explicitly specified in the uses list of the function's unit.
>
> If the inline function's code is to be expanded, then the unit that
>   calls the function must explicitly use the unit where the ancestor
>   type is exposed.

[H2443 Inline function has not been expanded](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/H2443_Inline_function_'%25s'_has_not_been_expanded_because_unit_'%25s'_is_not_specified_in_USES_list_(Delphi))